ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator is not working with double field
I am using ArcGIS Pro version 3.2.2.
I am trying to use Field Calculator on a point feature class, which was generated from a Kriging raster dataset using the GA Layer To Points tool. When I multiply the "Error" Field with self to get a squared error, I get a warning saying the table has no records and to use the Get Count tool, which is no help. Additionally, exporting the feature class as a shapefile results in an empty shapefile (with no records, ie., rows). Here is a screenshot:

Here is the link to the geodatabase containing the feature class
Interestingly, if I run the same process in ArcMap 10.8, it works.
Is there a bug in ArcGIS Pro?

I updated ArcGIS Pro to 3.3. The problem persists.

I some time experience this issue of a selection of nothing. I think it's a bug or at least some weird scenario that can illogically manifest itself. The solution I have found is to click on the clear selection button in the ribbon, then the selection set of nothing is removed. I might not have anything to do with the extent in some cases.

The issue was with the Processing Extent set in Environments. In an earlier step, I created a model using ModelBuilder and set its processing extent to one of the layers used in the ModelBuilder. For Kriging, I started a new Map view but I did not realize that setting processing extent in ModelBuilder gets applied/carried to all Map views.
I accessed the Environments (Geoprocessing) from Command Search and reset the processing extent; it worked. Here are screenshots to solutions.
Accessing Environments settings from Command search:

Resetting Processing extent in Environments settings:

